# How to bind UIElements in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a class:

```
class LinkedTextBox: TextBox
{
    public TextBox TextBoxA { get; set; }
    public TextBox TextBoxB { get; set; }
}
```

Say I have two Textboxes:

```
    <TextBox x:Name="txt1" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txt2" />
```

How do I to specify that TextBoxes on my Xaml?

My tests:

(1) "**The TypeConverter for "TextBox" does not support converting from a string.**"

```
    <local:LinkedTextBox TextBoxA="txt1" TextBoxB="txt2" />
```

(2) "**A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'TextBoxA' property of type 'LinkedTextBox'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.**"

```
    <local:LinkedTextBox 
        TextBoxA="{Binding ElementName=txt1}"  
        TextBoxB="{Binding ElementName=txt2}"  
        />
```

I think that there is an obvious way to do, but I don't know how to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right. Your second example is correct XAML, but it fails because `TextBoxA` and `TextBoxB` are the wrong kind of property. The target of a `Binding` must be a `DependencyProperty` of a `DependencyObject`, like it says on the tin. `TextBox` is already a `DependencyObject` and you're subclassing it, so that part's taken care of. And defining a `DependencyProperty` is trivial.

You would define `TextBoxA` like this, and `TextBoxB` likewise:

```
public class LinkedTextBox : TextBox
{
    #region TextBoxA Property
    public TextBox TextBoxA
    {
        get { return (TextBox)GetValue(TextBoxAProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextBoxAProperty, value); }
    }

    //  Careful with the parameters you pass to Register() here.
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxAProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxA", typeof(TextBox), typeof(LinkedTextBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
    #endregion TextBoxA Property
}
```

But what is your *intent* here? What are you trying to accomplish? <s>It's very likely that you can do it by binding existing properties to each other in a normal way, without any of these subclass monkeyshines. Possibly you'd want an [attached property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903943(v=vs.95).aspx), which is a specialized type of dependency property.</s>

## UPDATE

OP wants to add visual elements illustrating relationships among the text boxes. If you want to add a visual overlay, the WPF Way to Do That is to write [an Adorner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(v=vs.100).aspx). So you'd write some kind of `TextBoxLinkingAdorner` with `TextBoxA` and `TextBoxB` dependency properties, and apply that to the main text box, which depending on your requirements might not even have to be a subclass.

Your dependency properties might need to do some work when their values change; if so, they'd look more like this, assuming an `Adorner` subclass named `TextBoxLinkerAdorner`:

```
    #region TextBoxA Property
    public TextBox TextBoxA
    {
        get { return (TextBox)GetValue(TextBoxAProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextBoxAProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxAProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextBoxA", typeof(TextBox), 
            typeof(TextBoxLinkerAdorner),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                    TextBoxA_PropertyChanged)
                        { DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });

    protected static void TextBoxA_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, 
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = d as TextBoxLinkerAdorner;
    }
    #endregion TextBoxA Property
```

If all you're looking at on the text boxes is their size and location, you might write an adorner that links arbitrary `UIElements`, not just text boxes. The sky's the limit! If you can dream it, you can adorn it!

Comment: I will  "link" visually the Textboxes (really drawing lines), change the visual from both, maybe changing positions and then work with the text from both, proccessing and presenting the the results in the LinkedTextBox. I understand that the usual way is binding directly the properties, but I will need work with lot of properties, and I think really bad bind dozen of properties when I can bind the main UIElement directly. I will read about Attached Properties right now, thanks!

Comment: @ClickOk Ahhh, now I see where you're coming from. You might want to take a look at [Adorners](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(v=vs.100).aspx), which are the WPFish way to (among other things) "overlay visual decorations on a UIElement". The AdornerLayer would belong to the parent of the TextBoxes, I would think.